# Flutter dropdown menu items error when list is empty

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dropdown

I try to fill dropdown menu items from API JSON. I have `myList` in code. Sometimes, this list is empty and sometimes list has data.

If `myList` has data there is no problem. I am having trouble when `myList` is empty. How can I solve this?

My model class:

```
Login loginFromJson(String str) => Login.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String loginToJson(Login data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Login {
  Login({
    required this.token,
    required this.callListDto,
  });

  String token;
  List<CallListDto> callListDto;

  factory Login.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Login(
        token: json["token"],
        callListDto: List<CallListDto>.from(
            json["callListDto"].map((x) => CallListDto.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "token": token,
        "callListDto": List<dynamic>.from(callListDto.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class CallListDto {
  CallListDto({
    required this.callId,
    required this.stationCode,
    required this.callType,
  });

  int callId;
  String stationCode;
  int callType;

  factory CallListDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CallListDto(
        callId: json["callID"],
        stationCode: json["stationCode"],
        callType: json["callType"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "callID": callId,
        "stationCode": stationCode,
        "callType": callType,
      };
}
```

My dropdown UI:

```
items: _loginController.loginList[0].myList
      .where((p0) => p0.callType == 1)
      .map(
        (item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: item.callId.toString(),
          child: Text(
            item.callId.toString(),
            style: GoogleFonts.ptSansNarrow(
              textStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.8)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
      .toList(),
```

Comment: what error did you get ?

Comment: NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => CallListDto))

Answer (score 0):

make your value nullable you would no longer be able to access the dropdown button if no items are available in the list by default it will be disabled

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? val; //default value


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: DropdownButton(
          onChanged: (value){},
          value: val, // this is where you need to access it
          items: [].map((e) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
            value: e,
              child: Text(e),
            )
              ;
          }).toList(),
        
        )));
  }
}
```

Comment: NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => CallListDto))

Comment: I added my model class.

Comment: You can do like this:- List<Modelclass> name = list?? <Modelclass>[]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, if its null before.

```
callListDto: json["callListDto"] != null
            ? List<CallListDto>.from(
                json["callListDto"].map((x) => CallListDto.fromJson(x)))
            : <CallListDto>[]
```